# How can I use SQL server's sp_addsubscription via Java.sql objects

Tags: java, sql, sql-server

Given the following java code:

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);
con.setAutoCommit(false);
Statement s1 = con.createStatement();
s1.executeUpdate("exec sp_addsubscription @publication = N'TestPublication', @subscriber = N'testDB', @destination_db = N'DBPublish_replication2', @subscription_type = N'Push', @sync_type = N'automatic', @article = N'all', @update_mode = N'failover', @subscriber_type = 0");
```

I keep getting "The procedure 'sp_addsubscription' cannot be executed within a transaction" error.

A few details with regards to the users used:

1. user from the already has bulkadmin and sysadmin rights (in fact, I already checked all the server roles for this user)
2. the script runs smoothly without errorswhen used on sql management studio with a windows authenticated user

So what am I missing here? Am I missing any user privileges or something?

Comment: Try `setAutoCommit(true)`

Answer (score 0):

The error message is clear: you're trying to run the procedure within a transaction. For a repro in SSMS, throw a `begin tran` before the execution of the procedure; you should get the same error.